# List of functions applying to argument

Tags: haskell

Task is to make function, taking list of unary functions (+1,*2 etc.) **(3 at least)** and consistently applying them to argument. For example: func 1 [(+1),(+1),(/2)] == 1.5. Here's what i made:

```
compose x [(y),(c),(z)] =  map ($ x) [(z) . (c) . (y)]
```

But how can I make unlimited list of functions? In case if user wants more than 3 functions.
Another problem is that this function returns list with one element instead of just one element ([4] instead of 4) and I'm kinda stuck with it

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
compose x ys = foldl (\a b -> b a) x ys
```

This can be ETA reduced to be

```
compose = foldl (\a b -> b a)
```

or alternatively

```
compose x [] = x
compose x (y:ys) = compose (y x) ys
```

It applies the function to the input, then uses that input as the next input until it reaches the end of the list, and it then returns the final value.

```
λ> compose 1 [(+1), (+1), (/2)]
1.5
λ> compose 1 [(+1), (+1), (/2), (*10), (+(-1))]
14.0
λ> compose 1 []
1
λ>
```

Because of how haskell parses minuses, I think you have to make a minus function by adding a negative.

If the user has to enter at least 3 functions, you could do this:

```
compose x ys
    | length ys < 3 = error "Must enter at least 3 functions!"
    | otherwise = foldl (\a b -> b a) x ys
```

Alternatively, you could return a Maybe, as it's not very good style to error on something recoverable.

```
compose x ys
    | length ys < 3 = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just $ foldl (\a b -> b a) x ys
```

Comment: There's a condition: at least 3 functions (compose 1 [(+1),(+1)] shouldn't work). How can I control it?

Comment: As @Willem Van Onsem points out, you can use flip ($) instead of (\a b -> b a) which you might find cleaner.

Comment: @LokiTheCreator The requirement that it should not work with a shorter list is quite weird. Usually, in task assignments, we find requirements such as "it must work with lists of length >=3" instead of "it must fail on lists of length <3". I'd suggest to double check that failing is actually a requirement, since it seems likely that you are misreading the task description.

Answer (score 3):

## General problem

You can use `foldl` for this: in that case you pass an accumulator left-to-right over the list, and perform some operation over it:

So your `compose` then would look something like:

```
compose :: a -> [(a -> a)] -> a
compose x0 fs = foldl (??) x0 fs
```

So now the question is what we do in `??`. The first argument is the accumulator, the second an element of the list, a function. So we have to implement something like:

```
compose :: a -> [(a -> a)] -> a
compose x0 fs = foldl g x0 fs
    where g xi f = ...
```

we thus want to apply `f` to `xi` to obtain the next `xi`. Or in other words:

```
compose :: a -> [(a -> a)] -> a
compose x0 fs = foldl g x0 fs
    where g xi f = f xi
```

If we aim to simplify the `g` function, we can write it as:

```
compose :: a -> [(a -> a)] -> a
compose x0 fs = foldl g x0 fs
    where g = flip ($)
```

and further improve it to:

```
compose :: a -> [(a -> a)] -> a
compose = foldl (flip ($))
```

This then produces:

```
Prelude> foldl (flip ($)) 1 [(+1)]
2
Prelude> foldl (flip ($)) 1 [(+1),(+1)]
3
Prelude> foldl (flip ($)) 1 [(+1),(+1),(/2)]
1.5
```

## Three or more elements

If you want to restrict the number of elements to three or more, we can use pattern matching:

```
compose :: a -> [(a -> a)] -> a
compose x0 fs@(_:_:_:_) = foldl (flip ($)) x0 fs
```

although it is a bit weird that the program is not supposed to work on lists with no, one or two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Just two cases, zero functions or at least one.

```
compose x [] = x
compose x (f:fs) = compose (f x) fs
```

Answer (score 0):

This can simply be done by using [`foldr1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl1) to cascade the list functions by flipped compose operators

```
Prelude> foldr1 (flip (.)) [(+5),(/2),(*3)] $ 1
9.0
```